# Telerik RadGrid - Get Value from column on ItemUpdate event

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I've spend the last few hours trying to solve this, which i imagine is a easy fix.
However i haven't been able to find the solution yet.

In my grid im using:

```
AutoGenerateEditColumn="true"
```

When i press the Edit button in a row, i want to do a custom check in the RadGrid1_UpdateCommand event.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditColumn="true" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource">

<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" DataKeyNames="Id">
<Columns>

<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id" Display="false" ReadOnly="true">

<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name"/>

</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:radGrid>
```

And so in my backend i hook on the event like so:

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
// Get the ID for the specific row which had the "Edit" link pressed.
}
```

i would prefer if i was able to have the ID stored in a int.

```
int i = e.Somthing.Something.Darkside;
```

I have searched far and wide with no success and i hope someone can come to my rescue on this fine Friday.

I am sorry if i make no sense, English is not my primary language and my way of thinking may be off (Looking at something that should be simple for 3 hours does that to you doesn't it?).

Comment: MichaelA - based on the two answers you've got so far, did you want the row's index or the value of the column "Id"?

Comment: @DanM Hi DanM what i was looking for was the column "id" so Jayesh Goyani´s solution did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("Id").ToString());
    //Access edit row ID value here -- using datakey

    string Name = (item["Name"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    // Get Name field updated value here

    int index = item.ItemIndex;
    // Access edit row index here
}
```

Let me know if I am not understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler for `RadGrid1_UpdateCommand`, get the current item and then from there you can calculate the item's row index:

```
GridEditableItem editItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
int myIndex = (editItem.RowIndex / 2) - 1;
```

The `RowIndex` value is a multiple of 2, and is sort of 1's based (starts at 1, not zero).  So with this calculation, you get the following (what I consider what you would expect):

```
RowIndex    myIndex  
2           0
4           1
6           2
...
```